# Implemented LSTM inference code shows different test loss compared to using lasagne.

Tags: python, matlab, theano, lstm, lasagne

I have difficulty implementing LSTM inference code using matlab. I extraced weight from trained model using theano and lasagne. And then, i coded LSTM inference(test) code using extraced weights and biases.

The loss of implemented inference code shows about 5, but the test loss of theano and lasagne shows about 1.5.

I think implemented inference matlab code is correct and the code is like this.

```
for i=1:100
input1 = input(i,:);
input_gate=activation_sigmoid(mtimes(input1,W_in_to_ingate)+mtimes(hidden,W_hid_to_ingate)+reshape(b_ingate,1,512));
forget=activation_sigmoid(mtimes(input1,W_in_to_forgetgate)+mtimes(hidden,W_hid_to_forgetgate)+reshape(b_forgetgate,1,512));
output=activation_sigmoid(mtimes(input1,W_in_to_outgate)+mtimes(hidden,W_hid_to_outgate)+reshape(b_outgate,1,512));
cell=activation_tanh(mtimes(input1,W_in_to_cell)+mtimes(hidden,W_hid_to_cell)+reshape(b_cell,1,512));

ct=input_gate.*cell+forget.*ct;
hidden=activation_tanh(ct).*output;

result=softmax(reshape(mtimes(hidden,W)+reshape(b,1,83),83,1));
new_loss=-(log(result(answer(1,i)+1)));
loss = loss+new_loss;
end
loss=loss/100;
```

I have no idea which part is incorrect compared to lasagne LSTM source code.
The code using theano and lasagne is described below.

```
l_in = lasagne.layers.InputLayer(shape=(None, None, vocab_size))
l_forward_2 = lab.LSTMLayer(
            l_in, 
            num_units=N_HIDDEN,
            grad_clipping=GRAD_CLIP,
            peepholes=False,
            nonlinearity=activation, 
            method=method)   ### batch_size*SEQ_LENGTH*N_HIDDEN

l_shp = lasagne.layers.ReshapeLayer(l_forward_2, (-1, N_HIDDEN))  ## (batch_size*SEQ_LENGTH, N_HIDDEN)
l_out = lasagne.layers.DenseLayer(l_shp, num_units=vocab_size, W = lasagne.init.Normal(), nonlinearity=lasagne.nonlinearities.softmax)
batchsize, seqlen, _ = l_in.input_var.shape
l_shp1 = lasagne.layers.ReshapeLayer(l_out, (batchsize, seqlen, vocab_size))
l_out1 = lasagne.layers.SliceLayer(l_shp1, -1, 1)
test_output = lasagne.layers.get_output(l_out, deterministic=True)
test_loss = T.nnet.categorical_crossentropy(test_output,target.flatten()).mean()
val_fn = theano.function([l_in.input_var, target], test_loss, allow_input_downcast=True)
```

The input of LSTM layer and target label are made like this.

```
    def gen_data(pp, batch_size,SEQ_LENGTH, data, return_target=True):

    x = np.zeros((batch_size,SEQ_LENGTH,vocab_size))   ###### 128*100*85
    y = np.zeros((batch_size, SEQ_LENGTH))

    for n in range(batch_size):
        # ptr = n
        for i in range(SEQ_LENGTH):
            x[n,i,char_to_ix[data[pp[n]*SEQ_LENGTH+i]]] = 1.
            y[n,i] = char_to_ix[data[pp[n]*SEQ_LENGTH+i+1]]
    return x, np.array(y,dtype='int32')
```

I have been struggled with this problem about a month. I really need your help.

Thank you.